# Is it possible to use subprocess to execute uploaded python file in django?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I want to allow my company users to upload a python script and execute it. I am using subprocess to execute script but I am getting errors saying "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile"

```
def execute(request)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES.get('document'):
            file = request.FILES['document']
            subprocess.run(['python', file], stdout=True)
```

Comment: *"I want to allow my company users to upload a python script and execute it."* This sounds like a really bad idea!

Comment: What you have is a Django file object.  You can get the file name from `file.name`.  But as @KlausD. said, this is a really bad idea, easily exploitable to destroy your server.

Comment: @KlausD. it's not my idea. it's my boss's idea, I think he wants to use it for something.

Comment: @TimRoberts Would you mind to show me how's it done?

Comment: @TimRoberts, it's working.

Comment: It is a professional engineer's JOB to point out to management when he's been asked to implement something dangerous.  We are not automatons.